# How to remove Myaccount functionality in Magento?

Tags: php, customization, magento-1.9, user-accounts

Could you please help me to remove the Myaccount functionality in Magento? because I just want to create product inquiry site, in other word catalog website. I able remove the Myaccount links from the layout, but still can access via URL if someone knows it.

FYI: I'm currently using Magento 1.9.2.2v.

**EDIT**: I want to remove users/search engine accessing following page. Basically I want to disable myaccount feature as Magento has the ability to disable checkout (https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45802/how-can-i-disable-the-magento-shopping-cart ) and wishlist (http://inchoo.net/magento/disabling-wishlist-functionality/ ). 
[image]

My intention is to add a redirection to the .htaccess file and update robot.txt, but I'm really looking to do this in a correct way.

Comment: Can you send a link or screenshot for better understanding?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this question, I've added more information please see above.

Comment: @FRSTAR I have not worked on Magento yet, but just asking.. is this extension helpful to you? http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/remove-customer-account-links.html

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure because they don't have a latest version to test.

Answer (score 2):

Login into admin panel

> Goto -> System -> Configuration -> Advance
>
> In that Module Disable the "Mage_Customer" It will disable all customer access.

Comment: Thanks man, it did what I wanted but when I tested the following URL

http://www.{domain}/customer/account/forgotpassword/ it throws me the following error **Fatal error: Call to a member function setEmailValue() on a non-object in /home/group/public_html/ztest/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php on line 709** I believe simple redirection would be ideal?

Comment: There are some links which id give error but it will be never render in google so no need to resolve that. No once can get the access of direct url and you can add htaccess for  /customer to home page.

Answer (score 0):

In app\etc\modules\Mage_All.xml

Change

```
    <Mage_Customer>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>core</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Eav/>
            <Mage_Dataflow/>
            <Mage_Directory/>
        </depends>
    </Mage_Customer>
```

by

```
    <Mage_Customer>
        <active>false</active>
        <codePool>core</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Eav/>
            <Mage_Dataflow/>
            <Mage_Directory/>
        </depends>
    </Mage_Customer>
```